# How to connect to mysql database using Spring, Hibernate, EntityManager and JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm attempting to combine Spring, Hibernate, JPA with mysql. I have created some model, DAO and Service objects and I'm attempting to link the together via spring. The Hibernate is paring the model successful, but spring failing to create Hibernate SessionFactory:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [spring/config/Spring-Config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

My spring woodoo looks like this:

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Enable annotation configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scan JDBC Implementations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.rdswitchboard.linkers.neo4j.web.researcher.dao.jdbc.impl" />

    <!-- Scan Service Implementations -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.rdswitchboard.linkers.neo4j.web.researcher.service.impl" />

    <!-- Add properties file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.rdswitchboard.linkers.neo4j.web.researcher.model" />

        <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
             Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"> 
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Could any one tell me what is missing from this configuration? Do I have to separately create a bean for SpringFactory? And if no one knows answer to that, is there a way in Spring to tell exact reason why SessionFactory can not be build?

Update: It's turns out the problem was in JPA configuration

Comment: Did you create `persistence.xml` in `classpath:META-INF/` ?

Comment: No, it is not required if using JPA notations

Comment: You don't need to add entities there. Just try to create empty persistence xml config with empty `persistence-unit` section. Don't forget set name attribute of  `persistence-unit`.

Comment: I do not want to create  persistence.xml at all. As I understand, the JPA should be enough. I have added this line into Spring xml: <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.rdswitchboard.linkers.neo4j.web.researcher.model" /> and it does same as persistence xml. I have already make to spring work with this configuration, the reason it didn't want to was in JPA it self. I have combined key in one of databases and it has to be serealizable. Now I'm facing a new error, Spring kills session before I can fetch whole record with Lazy Fetch

Comment: It is well known problem. You can't use `Lazy` fetch in different transactions, since session is closing when transaction ends. Replace `Lazy` with `Eager` or fetch related entities manually with separate query.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However querying whole array every time will be too costly. Some time I just need to check if such record exists. Is there a way to initialise session after and make Lazy load work? I guess there should be one, because in other case what is the point of having Lazy loading?

Comment: @AliDehghani sorry, but what difference does it make?

Comment: Don't load it every time. Load it just once and store in memory until you need it. Unfortunately, there is no other ways while you using `JpaTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all these low level configuration problems if you use spring boot. Once you have it running, and you are still interested in it you can still try to find out how the configuration works.